# nginx rewrite url missing something

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have multiple dynamic urls at the root directory which needs to be written as following. e.g.

```
https://mv.test/review/4
https://mv.test/investment-banker/banking-products--004
```

1st url **/Reviews/** is working perfectly fine but 2nd url is going to 404 page. I am not able to understand why it's not working.

**Location blocks**

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}
location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}

location /review/ {
    rewrite "^/review/([0-9]+)$" /review.php?id=$1 last;
}
location /store/ {
    rewrite "^/(.*)/(.*)$" /store.php?store_type=$1&store_owner=$2 last;
}
```

Comment: Your first example URI does not match your first location block `location /review/ { ... }`, maybe you mean `/review/4` instead of `/reviews/4`? Moreover, you don't specify what to do with the URIs like `/review/some-non-digital-string`, generally you want to show some customized "not found" page. Your second example URI `/investment-banker/banking-products--004` obviously does not match your second location block `location /store/ { ... }` since it does not start with the `/store/` prefix.

Comment: Hi @IvanShatsky, thanks for highlighting /Reviews/ error. i have corrected it. for 2nd url, though file name {store.php} is currently in the root directory but i have tried it otherwise as well, by putting into store folder. If I put this rewrite code under root location block then also nothing works.

Comment: The `location /store/` must match the URL. So it only matches URLs like `https://mv.test/store/...` not `https://mv.test/investment...` - so its not clear why you expect that last block to rewrite the 2nd URL.

Comment: Hi @RichardSmith, I want to rewrite 2nd url with php script located at the root directory with name of `store.php`. Both query strings `investment-banker/banking-products--004` are dynamic in nature & will change to 21 different types of services. Though i am able to successfully rewrite url with `https://mv.test/store/investment-banker/banking-products--004`. But i wish to rewrite as `https://mv.test/investment-banker/banking-products--004`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly `https://example.com/investment-banker/banking-products--004` does not match `location /store/`, so it will be processed by the default `location` which is `location /`.

You want to rewrite `https://foo/bar` to `/store.php?store_type=foo&store_owner=bar` for any foo/bar that does not match another legitimate URI already handled by the server.

At the moment the `location @extensionless-php` block will blindly rewrite the URL to `/foo/bar.php` whether the PHP file exists or not.

This can be improved with an `if` block.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}
location @extensionless-php {
    if (-f $document_root$uri.php) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /store.php?store_type=$1&store_owner=$2 last;
}    
location /review/ {
    rewrite ^/review/([0-9]+)$ /review.php?id=$1 last;
}
```